What is the difference between return NULL and pthread_exit(NULL) while terminating the detached thread
I am trying to understand what happens when we return NULL from the thread and what happens when we call pthread_exit(NULL) from the thread?
I am not able to understand when to use what?
Can somebody please explain? Help will be appreciated.
I tried creating separate threads, one terminates with return NULL and the other terminates with pthread_exit(NULL) but couldn't find the difference between the both.
Keeping in mind that the main() terminates with calling pthread_exit(NULL)

From the pthread_create documentation: "The new thread terminates in one of the following ways: [...] It returns from start_routine().  This is equivalent to calling pthread_exit(3) with the value supplied in the return statement".  So they should be equivalent.

You might need to use pthread_exit() if you want to terminate the thread while nested many functions deep, without returning out of them all, which might be tedious and tricky to do correctly.

It is important to understand that returning from main calls exit, not pthread_exit. This is one of the few differences between the initial thread and all other threads.
